# Mailer-Plugin not showing in Application's Dependencies

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I am trying to use [the Mailer Plugin](https://github.com/typesafehub/play-plugins/tree/master/mailer) in my play! 2 Java Application.
I followed the Instructions given in the Readme File but the Module doesn't show up in my Application's Dependencies.
So when I try to compile it play! gives me an error:

```
object plugin is not a member of package com.typesafe
```

I tried to reload the project and double-checked the files in `/project`. Nothing worked so far.

Is there a way to force play! to check the application's dependencies?

**Update:**

Ok, new Error Message. I deleted `/project/project/`, `/project/target/` and `/target/`. Next time I started play! it took quite some time to get all the Modules. It did not download the Mailer-Plugin.
But now I get:

```
play.api.PlayException: Cannot load plugin [Plugin [com.typesafe.plugin.CommonsMailerPlugin] cannot been instantiated.]
```

followed by:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.typesafe.plugin.CommonsMailerPlugin
```

Any Ideas?

**Update 2:**
Okay, i *fixed* this by downloading the play-plugins-mailer_2.9.1-2.0.4.jar directly from typesafe and putting it into `/lib`. This is definitely not the right way, but at least it works for now.
The .jar I needed for my play! 2.0.3 project: http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play-plugins-mailer_2.9.1/2.0.4/

**Update 3:**
Content of relevant Files:
Build.scala:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import PlayProject._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

    val appName         = "thesis"
    val appVersion      = "0.9"

    val appDependencies = Seq(
        "com.typesafe" %% "play-plugins-mailer" % "2.0.4"
    )

    val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, mainLang = JAVA).settings(
        lessEntryPoints <<= baseDirectory(_ / "app" / "assets" / "stylesheets" ** "bootstrap.less"),
        templatesImport += "helper._",
        templatesImport += "views.html.Helpers._"
    )

}
```

build.properties:

```
sbt.version=0.11.3
```

plugins.sbt:

```
// Comment to get more information during initialization
logLevel := Level.Info

// The Typesafe repository
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.0.3")
```

conf/play.plugins:

```
1500:com.typesafe.plugin.CommonsMailerPlugin
```

Comment: Please show your `Build.scala` file.

Comment: Do you need the whole file or just the `appDependencies` part? `val appDependencies = Seq(
  "com.typesafe" %% "play-plugins-mailer" % "2.0.4"
 )`

Comment: I just tested it, and it works for me... Did you try in the Play console `reload`, then `clean` and then `compile` ?

Comment: Yes, tried that. I even deleted some Folders to force play to update the dependencies but it doesn't download the .jar!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, in order to get play! to manage my dependencies I had to create a new project copy over the old files (excluding already compiled code), edit the `Build.scala` and reload/compile the project inside the play! console.
Now it works! Mailer Plugin gets downloaded, compiled and `play dependencies` lists it.